# How to save a trained Pipeline model into a single tflite file?

Tags: python, pipeline

I trained a Pipeline model, which uses `CountVectorizer`, `TfidfTransformer`, `OneVsRestClassifier` and also a `GridSearchCV`.

Now I want to save it into a tflite file, to use it on my Android app.

For a Sequential model (where my tflite file was created successfully), I did:

```
sequential_model = Sequential()
...
# train and fit the model
...

h5_file = "h5_model.h5"
tflite_file = "tflite_model.tflite"

sequential_model.save(h5_file)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(h5_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(tflite_file, "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

All good to save Sequential model into a tflite file.

Well, Pipeline has no attribute "save", unlike a Sequential model, so I tried saving the Pipeline model with `joblib` and then with `pickle`, but none of them worked.

Let's say that `pipeline_model` is my trained model (the one described in the first sentence).

```
pb_file = 'pipeline_model.pb'
# I also tried with other extensions, like h5, hdf5, sav, pkl

joblib.dump(pipeline_model, filename)
# or with pickle equivalent and pkl extension
# pickle.dump(pipeline_model, open(pb_file, 'wb'))
```

Now the pb file is created and I want to create a tflite one. Since it's not a Keras model, I can't use `from_keras_model_file`, so I tried instead with `from_saved_model`.

```
pb_file = 'pipeline_model.pb'
tflite_file = "tflite_model.tflite"    

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(pb_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

open(tflite_file, "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

It generates the error on line of `converter = ...`:

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: pb_file.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

I tried running it on Kaggle, Colab, PyCharm IDE, with both versions of tensorflow (1 and 2), with different file extensions and nothing seems to work.

I also noticed that TFLiteConverter contains the methods `from_frozen_graph` and `from_session`, but these two requires an extra parameter, so I don't think these could be the solution.

So, how can I obtain my tflite file from the trained Pipeline model? Please, if you find any solution, tell me the library versions that you used, since there could be a different behaviour on different libs.